# How to check if an ArrayList contains an object from another class

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two classes, a `Fighter` class and a `Player` class. The `Player` class contains an `ArrayList` called `fleet` that is populated with a player's ships.

I can add ships to the player's fleet without issue, but when I try check to see if a fighter is present in the player's fleet, it gives me an error saying `Fighter cannot be resolved to a variable`.

I'm confused as to why I can add a Fighter to fleet, but can't check to see if a Fighter is present in fleet.

**Fighter.java**

```
public class Fighter extends Ship {
    public Fighter(){
        super(9,1,1); //Sets attack and defense values
    }
}
```

**Player.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Player {

    ArrayList<Ship> fleet = new ArrayList<Ship>();

    public void takeAHit(){
        if (fleet.contains(Fighter)){                  //Error happens here
            System.out.println("Fighter found");
        }
    }

    public void buildFleet(){

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many fighters?");

        int fighters = Integer.parseInt(userInput.next());

        while (fighters > 0){
            fleet.add(new Fighter());
            fighters--;
        }

        userInput.close();

    }
}
```

**Core.java**

```
public class Core {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Player p1 = new Player();
        p1.buildFleet();
        p1.takeAHit();

    }
}
```

Comment: If you wanted to check for a class, you would use `Fighter.class`, but I'm not sure that would work.

Comment: It did make the error go away, but it doesn't find the fighter when I run the program.

Comment: You may have to use a `for each` method and check if each `entry.class == Fighter.class` Thats the only way I can think of. Someone else may have a better option

Comment: Where do you call buildFleet? Seems like fleet doesn't contain a fighter.

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't include my Core.java file. It just runs in in my main method. I've added my Core.java above.

Comment: You have a variable `Fighters` which is going to be confusing. By [convention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) variables should never start with an upper-case character, in order to distinguish them from classes which should always start with an upper-case character. Using `fighters` instead would make it clearer, visually, that the class name `Fighter` isn't a variable and can't be passed to the `.contains()` method.

Comment: I've edited my code to follow convention better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `contains` method needs an instance of the class and not the class itself.
And to reference a class, you need to append `.class` to the name.

The best solution I can think of is to create a method that uses the `instanceof` keyword similar to:

```
public boolean isFighterInFleet() {
    for(Ship ship : this.fleet)
        if(ship instanceof Fighter)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Then use:

```
if (isFighterInFleet()){
```

instead of

```
if (fleet.contains(Fighter)){
```

Comment: I believe that should be `public boolean isFighterInFleet()`

Comment: @TaylorLiss Changed it

Comment: would it be possible for this code to be modular for different types of ships? i.e. could I somehow pass in the name of the class i want to check for and have it search for that type of ship?

Comment: You can add an argument of type `Class<?>` and the `if` statement use `ship.getClass().equals(argument)`. Make sure to replace `argument` with your actual argument name.

Comment: Haha awesome! Perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8:

> this.fleet.stream().filter(ship -> ship instanceof
>   fighter).findFirst().isPresent() ;

Comment: anyMatch would probably be more straightforward